# How can I pass a generic class in my method so that this code becomes reusable

Tags: c#, generics

Class I call every-time I need to pass a new page class I have to build a new Constructor, I know generics will solve this. Can someone show me how this can be done?

```
 public class CheckUserAuthentication
    {
        private Page1 _p1;   
        private Page2 _p2;


        public CheckUserAuthentication(Page1 p1)
        {
            _p1 = p1;
        }

        public CheckUserAuthentication(Page2 p2)
        {
            _p2 = p2;
        }

  public void AuthenticateUser(out Person person, out Animal animal) 
        {
           If(_p1 != null)
             {
            _p1.Response.Write("writes to P1 page");

             }
            else
             {
             _p2.Response.Write("writes to P2 page");
             }
        }
    }
```

My calling code for Page 1

```
public Page1()
{
    _checkUserAuthentication = new CheckUserAuthentication(this);
}

public CheckUserAuthentication CheckUserAuthentication
{
    get { return _checkUserAuthentication; }
}

CheckUserAuthentication.AuthenticateUser(out person, out animal);
```

Comment: Without a more complete implementation of `CheckuserAuthentication` it is hard to give you help. You have instance AND static methods.. we would need to see both sorts to give you a clean example.

Comment: Ill add more to it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using an interface:

```
public interface IPage {
    public HttpResponse Response { get; set; }
}

public class Page1 : IPage {
}

public class Page2 : IPage {
}

public class CheckuserAuthentication {
    private IPage _page;

    public CheckuserAuthentication(IPage page) {
        _page = page;
    }

    public void AuthenticateUser(out Person person, out Animal animal) {
        _page.Response.Write("Doesn't matter what page it writes to.. it will write to whatever you pass in..");
    }
}
```